# Incompatible type exception occurs when using the each function in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, database, each, dolphindb

I want to calculates the maximum value of each column in a table.The table is defined as bellow,

```
t = table(1 2 3 as id, 4 5 6 as value, `IBM`MSFT`GOOG as name);
```

When I calculates the first 2 columns, it is OK.

```
>each(max, t[`id`value]);
[3,6]
```

But I calculates all columns as bellow,

```
each(max, t[`id`value`name]);
```

Incompatible type exception occurs [image: like this]

Can you tell me what is wrong? Thank you！

Answer (score 0):

Higher order function `each` requires the return of individual has identical type. In your case, the last sub-tasks returns a string, which is incompatible with the result of first two sub-tasks. Please switch from `each` to `loop` and the final result will be a tuple containing mixed types of data.